# Final statement returns character instead of character varying

Tags: postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 10.5 on Azure. I want to create a stored procedure that returns a set of rows, so I copy the types of the selected data from the setup script:

```sql
DROP TYPE t CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE t as (region varchar(24), county varchar(50), year int, value int);
DROP FUNCTION geo();
CREATE FUNCTION geo()
returns setof t language sql as $$
SELECT
region.name, county.name, tbl.year, tbl.value
FROM tbl
LEFT JOIN county ON tbl.lau1 = county.lau1
LEFT JOIN region ON county.regionid = region.regionid
$$;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return t
DETAIL:  Final statement returns character instead of character varying at column 1.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "geo"
```

Yet, the types are the same as in the creation of the `region` and `county` tables (and I also include the code for `tbl`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE county (

    LAU1    CHAR(9),
    NAME    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    REGIONID    INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(LAU1)
);

CREATE TABLE region (
    REGIONID    SMALLINT,
    NAME        VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(REGIONID)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl (
    LAU1        CHAR(9),
    YEAR        INT,
    VALUE       INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(LAU1, YEAR)
);
```

A sample of the three tables:

```
=> select * from county limit 2;
   lau1    |   name    | regionid 
-----------+-----------+----------
 E06000015 | Derby     |        4
 E06000016 | Leicester |        4
(2 rows)

=> select * from region limit 2;
 regionid |           name           
----------+--------------------------
        1 | North East              
        2 | North West              
(2 rows)

=> select * from tbl limit 2;
   lau1    | year | value 
-----------+------+-------
 E06000047 | 1997 |  3241
 E06000005 | 1997 |   656
(2 rows)
```

I would like to keep the same type in the returned values as the original type of `varchar`. But as an experiment, if I change the first type of the tuple from a `varchar` to a `char`:

```
CREATE TYPE t as (region char(24), county varchar(50), year int, value int);
```

and the rest of the code as before, then it works, despite the second column keeping the `varchar`!

```
select * from geo();
          region          |   county   | year | value 
--------------------------+------------+------+-------
 North East               | Hartlepool | 1997 |   625
(1 row)
```

How come?

Comment: There is no `tbl` and `country` defined in the query. This will give a syntax error. Please show your real data.

Comment: No, indeed. I now updated the question to include the code that creates the table `tbl` and samples of the three tables. Note that the table is `county`, not `country`.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't update the definition of the function `geo` that contains the incorrect SQL statement.

Comment: You're right. I did the replacements now, and for clarity they were `onsincome -> tbl` and `la -> county`.

Comment: Thanks! I ran your example, and there is no error. Perhaps you simplified the problem away somehow.

Comment: Indeed, I checked out the original code from version control and now it works without a problem, either the full script or the snippet that replaces the type and stored procedure. The version of PostgreSQL is the same `10.5`. It runs on Azure. Maybe Microsoft pushed a minor version change in the last 3 days? Otherwise I don't know what the problem was.